# how to replace line in a text file in java

Tags: java, file

I am reading a text file and wanted to replace the line which matches the regex pattern
   {`pattern = "^[0-9]+[\\s]*";`}

and mycode is :

```
sc = new Reader();
        out = new PrintWriter (System.out, true);
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
        PDDocument pdDoc = null;
        COSDocument cosDoc = null;
        File file ;
        try {

            pdDoc = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\Users\\Vivek\\Desktop\\novels\\The-End-of-Days-an-Adventure-Love-Story-for-Adults.pdf"));
            pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
            pdfStripper.setEndPage(492);


            String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);

            String pattern = "^[0-9]+[\\s]*";
            parsedText=parsedText.replaceAll(pattern, " ");
            try
            {
                String filename= "C:\\Users\\Vivek\\Desktop\\novels\\Me1.txt";
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true); //the true will append the new data
                fw.write(parsedText);//appends the string to the file
                fw.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
            }


          //  out.println(parsedText);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
```

I try many codes but nothing works.

Comment: Your regex is missing end of line sign - $. Add it and try again.

Comment: how to add it.plz tell me

Comment: ^[0-9]+[\\s]*$ . I would advice you to go to regex101.com and play around. Your regex seems to accept only digits. Is that what you want?

Comment: yup only want to delete the page number

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove empty line in a file in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40693895/how-to-remove-empty-line-in-a-file-in-java)